# Blocking CSS Resources

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have read a ton of tutorials and "fixes" to defer or asynchronously load CSS... 3 hours later and a huge headache i'm going to bed....

google page speed test: Your page has 3 blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.

Ive read javascript methods, jquery methods and a ton of answers all around the net... Feeling abit stupid can someone please explain in lamens how the heck to make these load without using inline css...

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: Have you tried applying styles after page load, or page speed test?

Comment: can you be more specific please. sorry i did make my site www.zachnewberry.com but im not a webmaster by any means Im a roofer with a low marketing budget :P

Comment: If your concern is *oogle   page speed test, you could load the `css` resources after page is loaded; that is following the dispatch of `DOMContentLoaded` and `window` `load` event. Why is *oogle page speed test important to you?

Comment: well im under the assumption it will help google rank my page higher. I use site-analyzer and I have scored 90+ on all tests wich im satisfied with. but the page speed is bugging me from google. My primary goal is to have google rank me as high as possible before I let organic traffic and my ppc help

Comment: Have you contacted *oogle to ask them what could be done to achieve your goal, without purchasing a product?  How essential is the `css` to the page? You could load the `css` at `Worker` or `ServiceWorker` , when `load` is dispatched at `window`, create a single `<style>` element and append the `css` text to the element `.textContent`.

Comment: Seriously you should look at this `bootstrap.min.css` file. Render blocking not always caused by inappropriate calling, sometimes it is due to CSS content. This file contains probably thousand lines of coding that browser never uses. Just select parts you are using and eliminate the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I've some experiences with render blocking files. So I share it in hope to help but you should know this solving this problem is a little tricky and not as straight forward as you wish. Ask yourself these three questions first:
First: Is your content prioritized?
Second: Do you use WordPress?
if you do
Three: Are you sure you have not installed some interfering plugins?

First: HTML5 semantics for content prioritization are essential but there is a possibility using them wrong. For example one element like a sidebar may be visible in above the fold content but it isn't considered as the above the fold. You know render blocking means: the loading page needs something that isn't there at the right time and it should wait. The unwanted element may lead to this situation.
Second: If you use WordPress and you have bought some theme for it, then probably your theme isn't standard. The problem could be solved but not worth it, it takes time and you should think about next theme updates. Changing your theme is the easiest I think, however correcting it is possible. But if you use some static pages, just call CSS files as soon as possible.
Three: Lately I had such a problem for all of my CSS and JavaScript files. It was due to use a plugin for lazy loading the images. It messed with everything, I deactivated it and problem solved. It defers images loading and gain some advantages but defer total page loading to download all the files, more Cons than Pros! Go through your plugin for something that may have an influence.
I've still one render blocking CSS but I'm working on it. I use a plugin for merging CSS files and render blocking is caused by that. I am eliminating as much as plugins I can, and build their abilities in a child theme to reduce CSS files request then I can deactivate this merging plugin.

Comment: I dont use wordpress, the content is not "priotized" for the landing page. I beleive this is because text/code ratio

Comment: @zachnewberry I can look at your page if you don't mind. And what about calling CSS files ASAP? Is it possible for you?

Comment: sure, https://www.zachnewberry.com is the website. If you want to look at some of the source shoot me a email zach (at) zachnewberry.com

Comment: @zachnewberry I went through your pages, your main page content isn't prioritized because there are several `<header>` tags. ONLY ONE `<header>` tag is allowed, delete others. I've created [this sample page](http://www.21tech.ir/stackoverflow/test2.html) with just one JavaScript render blocking, it could be solved too by pasting that file codes into the main page but it makes page a little heavy. Now I've no better idea. َAlso look at my version of your images, their weight are nearly one third and look just fine. Probably compressing your images has better effect on page loading speed.

Comment: @zachnewberry Another thing about page performance came to my mind, you use three icon of font-awesome, then why you load a 27KB external CSS with hundreds of icons?

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful insights ill work on this today! I thought I had my images as good as they can get ill also check into it all

Comment: Im looking at the font awsome css.. having a hard time figuring out what to keep and delete for only my 3 icons to work properly.

Comment: @zachnewberry Delete those ones have name like this: `.fa-play`. There are more than 700 of them.